# asp.net based feature to auto switch of CSS files

Tags: asp.net

Is there is any feature that enable auto switch of css files based on different browsers.

I don't want to use javascript code for browser detection and switch of css files.

As browser files in asp.net help in loading different css props for different server controls on runtime. Is there is any feature for us to use for auto switching of css files

Thanks

Comment: Why change per browser? Are you trying to make your control look different in every browser? support different properties? what is your objective in mind?

Answer (score 0):

This would bring in a lot of overhead in development and maintenance. The typical way in supporting multiple browsers is by creating a main stylesheet for you site which covers your targeted devices. You also rely heavily on the knowledge stored in those browser files. What if the user agent string is not the actual browser visiting the site?

Use techniques such as:

- Utilising vendor prefixes -webkit- -moz- etc.
- Media Queries
- Ensuring you use percentages as much as possible, fluid layouts.
- & Lots of Trial and Error

If this is to cover older versions of IE then you can utilise IE stylesheets and IE selectors.

As described in the Holy Bible for CSS: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

I know this is not the sort of thing you looking for but I feel your going down a very bumpy and messy road.

Thanks,

Mike